# Python Dictionaries where the keys are from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value, key-value-store

How can I print the certain values of a dictionary,where I should iterate it’s keys from a list?

F.e. -> I have a list with codons: [‘AUU’,’GGG’], and let’s assume that auu and ggg is defined in a dictionary as keys, and their values are x and y, I want to be able to read the list throughoutly, and print x and y.

Thanks for the help..

Comment: `for codon in codons: print(theDict[codon])`?

Comment: You should add the code which you tried and the errors you get if there was any. So people can help you with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
keys = ['auu', 'ggg']
a_dict = {'auu': 'x', 'ggg': 'y', 'hhh': 'z'}

for i in keys:
    print(a_dict[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using items() method -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/

```
a_dict = {'auu': 'x', 'ggg': 'y', 'hhh': 'z'}

for a, b  in a_dict.items():
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job,

```
test = {"AUU": "x", "GGG": "y"}  

for key in test:
  print(test[key])
```

**OR**

```
test = {"AUU": "x", "GGG": "y"}  

for value in test.values():
  print(value)
```

Both the code return the same output.

Output -

```
x
y
```

---

If you want to store the values in a list just use,

```
list(test.values())
```

`test.value()` returns you an object of type `dict_values` which isn't iterable. So passing it inside `list()` converts it into list, making it iterable.